# How to toggle Quarkus file log handlers

Tags: quarkus

[Quarkus] How can we toggle the file log handlers

I am trying to use file handlers and want to configure if that file handler should be enabled or disabled

I am using this property

```
quarkus.log.handler.file."myHandler".enable=${myHandlerShouldBeEnabled}
quarkus.log.handler.file."myHandler".format=${someFormat}

quarkus.log.category."com.mypackage".handlers"=myHandler
```

But even on setting `myHandlerShouldBeEnabled=false`, logs are getting written to file.

Any suggestion will be helpful

Comment: How is `myHandlerShouldBeEnabled` being set?

Comment: Hi @geoand 

I have set simple another property to control enable/disable in application.properties
myHandlerShouldBeEnabled = false
Even setting quarkus.log.handler.file."myHandler".enable=false directly 
is not preventing logging to file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed a bug that I reported [here](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/17913) based on this question.
It should be fixed by [this](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/17914) Pull Request.

Comment: Thanks @geoand !! so in which version it should be available

Comment: It will likely be available in `2.0.0.Final`

Comment: This issue is still reproducible in 2.0.0.Final

Comment: If that is the case, please comment on the Pull Request

Comment: Version was not updated at my end, after updation it is working well,
Thanks!!